# Running WCF Service on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service application with most basic settings working properly on my local computer. I had the error below when i deploy it on my test application server;

Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070032
Config Error    The configuration section 'system.serviceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

When i tried to deploy it test db server it worked properly.

After all searching i ended up with the problem on my test application server is that it has no Application Server role.

It seems there is no Application Server Role on Window Web Server 2008 R2 operation system.

So is there anyway / workaround to make my service work on Window Web Server 2008 R2 ?

Thanks.

---

Edit: I have two test machines. One for database (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard) one for applications (Windows Web Server 2008 R2)

My web.config file content is below;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Check this link .. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754024(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but i had to answer my own question.

Short and simple; if you use WCF, do not use Windows Web Server 2008 R2. You will need the application server role, and Web Server 2008 R2 has no application server role. You can find further details on the net about this issue.([WCF Service Issue on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744549/wcf-service-issue-on-windows-server-2008-r2))

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, there is a section missing in web.config.

What OS is the test machine running?

If you're hosting the service in IIS and have copied web.config from the test machine, you might need to add a System.WebServer section (this is a requirement of IIS 7).

If this doesn't help, please post your web.config.  Also there might be more detailed information in the event viewer.

Comment: Anything in the event log (click start and type 'event viewer')?

Comment: I checked and there was no any logs in event viewer.
We changed our production server operation system to Windows Server 2008 Standart edition. Lots of work...

I think it is so absurd that wcf services does not work on web server edition though.